# Hide command arguments in PHP exec()

Tags: php, linux, hide, exec

I have a script, written in C, which requires 3 parameters: host, name, password, like this:

`./myscript 1.1.1.1 name mypassword`

I call this using PHP exec command (need to, functionality not found in PHP).

`exec('./myscript $host $name $password');`

In linux, using ps command, I can see:

`./myscript 1.1.1.1 name password.`

How can I hide my password, that you can't see it on linux using ps?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need other outputs from `./myscript` or can it be run by another process ie. you need know data returned from it if so add `&` should do the trick like so `exec(./myscript $host $name $password &')` this will basically spawn another process to handle exec ... (similar to a thread in this situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are example out there which does something you like:
http://www.lenzg.net/archives/256-Basic-MySQL-Security-Providing-passwords-on-the-command-line.html
Remember, your password is still visible for a fraction of time.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a running environment. I'd temporary store your password in an environment variable (`SET`) and use this variable in your `exec()`. This way your password won't show up in `ps`.

Comment: A little example pls.
P.S. name and password are changing (they are for users authentication)

Comment: Since you already accepted an answer i doubt this is still userfull, but for setting an environment variable: http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php

Answer (score 1):

You could simply prompt the password after starting the executing of the C-script and forward the password via an pipe in PHP exec.